# Show $0 \leq u < 1$ for $u_t - \Delta u = u(u-1).$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the following PDE on the unit sphere with $t > 0$,
$$ u_t - \Delta u = u(u-1),
$$
and $0 \leq u < 1$ on all the boundaries, meaning on $\{(x,t) : |x| = 1, t > 0\} \cup \{(x,t) : |x| < 1, t = 0\}$.  Prove $0 \leq u < 1$ on the entire domain for all finite time.

---

I'm stumped.  Of course it seems to make intuitive sense, without the RHS we just have the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Knowing that $u$ starts in $[0,1],$ one can be convinced that the nonlinear forcing on the RHS won't push $u$ outside of $[0,1],$ as the forcing gets smaller where the value of $u$ is near 0 or 1.  But this intuition doesn't get me too far when it comes to actually proving this.  Any suggestions? I feel like some sort of perturbation (such as $v = u + \epsilon e^{\lambda t}$) would work, but I haven't been successful with it yet.

All comments are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Try applying the parabolic maximum principle.

Comment: Sure that works great when there is no nonlinear term... but what do we do about the $u(u-1)?$

Comment: FYI, I have figured it out, so no need to spend time writing out a solution, unless you feel so inclined :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by showing that $u \geq 0.$  Let $v = u + \epsilon e^{t}.$  Ultimately, if we can show that $v > 0$ on the domain, then as $\epsilon \to 0$ we get $u \geq 0.$  Notice that $v(x,0) > 0.$  Time-differentiating $v,$

$$v_t = \epsilon e^{t} + \Delta v + (v - \epsilon e^{t})(v-\epsilon e^{t}-1).$$

Suppose $v = 0$ at some $(x,t),$ and show a contradiction.  Consider the first time that $v = 0.$ This would be a local minimum, so $\Delta v \geq 0,$ $v_t \leq 0.$  Then, 
$$ 0 = -v_t + \Delta v +\epsilon e^{t}(\epsilon e^{t}+1) + \epsilon e^{t} > 0$$
since $\epsilon  >0.$  Thus, a contradiction, meaning $u \geq 0.$

---

In a similar vein, we can use this to show $u < 1,$ but we need a different perturbation.  Let $v = u - 1 +\epsilon - \mu e^{kt}.$  Then if we choose $\epsilon > 0$ small enough so that $v(x,0) < 0,$ and we can show that $v < 0$ for any $\mu > 0,$ then $u + \epsilon \leq 1,$ or $u < 1$ strictly.  So we time differentiate $v,$
$$ v_t = \Delta v + (v + 1 -\epsilon + \mu e^{-kt})(v -\epsilon + \mu e^{kt}) - k\mu e^{kt}.
$$

Suppose there is a time when $v = 0,$ then at this local maximum, we have,
$$ 0 = -v_t + \Delta v + (1-\epsilon + \mu e^{kt})(\mu e^{kt}-\epsilon) - k\mu e^{kt}
$$
or
$$ 0 = -v_t + \Delta v - (\mu e^{kt}-\epsilon)^2 + \mu e^{kt}-\epsilon  - k\mu e^{kt} < 0 .
$$
for $k$ large enough, thus a contradiction.